# MySQL sub query with two columns - how to hide the second column?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a difficult time wrapping my head around how to do this, even with all the searching and reading I've done on this!

I have a query I am using to try to pull all users from a database that have a zip code that falls within a certain distance of a given decimal coordinate. Here's the query that I am running:

```
select distinct watch_list.username, enabled 
from watch_list, registered_users 
where watch_list.username = registered_users.username AND watch_list.watchzip = (
  SELECT zip,
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('29.7632800') ) *
     cos( radians( lat ) ) *
     cos( radians( lng ) -
     radians('-95.3632700') ) +
     sin( radians('29.7632800') ) *
     sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )
  AS distance from zip 
  HAVING distance <= '10');
```

There error I get back is expected, as my sub query is returning two columns:

> ```
> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
> ```

How can I do this and filter on the distance without the sub query returning both columns?

P.S. Just for completion and information sake, the "zip" table contains a list of all zip codes in the U.S. along with their decimal coordinates.

Comment: The "," after zip gives you two columns.

Comment: Learn to use proper explicit `join` syntax.  Your query will fail if two zip codes are within the given radius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the operation out of the column list:

```
select distinct watch_list.username, enabled
from watch_list, registered_users
where watch_list.username = registered_users.username
      AND watch_list.watchzip = (
          SELECT zip
          from zip
          WHERE ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('29.7632800') ) *
                  cos( radians( lat ) ) *
                  cos( radians( lng ) -
                  radians('-95.3632700') ) +
                  sin( radians('29.7632800') ) *
                  sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) <= '10');
```

**Edit:** As P.Salmon mentions, you probably also want to change `AND watch_list.watchzip =` to `AND watch_list.watchzip IN`.

Comment: Change AND watch_list.watchzip = to AND watch_list.watchzip IN ?